# Find all strings that are in between two sub strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string as an example:

```
string = "@@ cat $$ @@dog$^"
```

I want to extract all the stringa that are locked between "@@" and "$", so the output will be:

```
[" cat ","dog"]
```

I only know how to extract the first occurrence:

```
import re
r = re.compile('@@(.*?)$')
m = r.search(string)
if m:
   result_str = m.group(1)
```

Thoughts & suggestions on how to catch them all are welcomed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to get every occurrence of your substring. `$` is considered a special character in regular expressions meaning — "*the end of the string*" anchor, so you need to escape `$` to match a literal character.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '@@ cat $$ @@dog$^'
>>> re.findall(r'@@(.*?)\$', s)
[' cat ', 'dog']
```

To remove the leading and trailing whitespace, you can simply match it outside of the capture group.

```
>>> re.findall(r'@@\s*(.*?)\s*\$', s)
['cat', 'dog']
```

Also, if the context has a possibility of spanning across newlines, you may consider using negation.

```
>>> re.findall(r'@@\s*([^$]*)\s*\$', s)
```

Comment: I suppose minifying might get people out of some newline problems too.